# Bug in cv::Orb?

Tags: opencv

I recently found some very strange behavior in opencv's [ORB](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html) descriptor.

```
cv::Mat grey; //greyscale image
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
cv::Mat descriptors;
cv::ORB detector;
detector(grey,cv::Mat(),keypoints,descriptors);
```

The above code consistently crashes if given an image containing no potential keypoints (a black image for example) with the error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (m.dims >= 2) in Mat, file /Users/user/slave/ios_framework/src/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 268
```

I found that to fix the problem I could do the following

```
cv::Mat grey;
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
cv::Mat descriptors;
cv::ORB detector;
detector(grey,cv::Mat(),keypoints);
if(keypoints.size() > 0)
{
    detector(grey,cv::Mat(),keypoints,descriptors,true);
}
```

Which first detects keypoints and then generates their descriptors if any keypoints were detected.  I am using opencv2 as a .framework on iOS.

Is this a bug in OpenCV?  If not, what am I doing wrong?  If so, are there any versions in which it is fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran this code

```
cv::Mat grey = cv::Mat::zeros(100, 100, CV_8UC1);
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
cv::Mat descriptors;
cv::ORB detector;
detector(grey,cv::Mat(),keypoints,descriptors);
```

with OpenCV 2.4.1 without problems.

Did you debug into your code to see where exactly the assertion fails?

Comment: yes, it fails on the line detector(grey,cv::Mat(),keypoints,descriptors);  Are you sure you supplied it with an image for which it can generate no keypoints? (pure white or pure black)

Comment: Yes, I ran exactly the code you can see above, `cv::Mat::zeros(100, 100, CV_8UC1)` returns a 100 x 100 pixel 8 bit image with all black pixels. You could also try setting your input image to this, if it works then, I assume your input image isn't loaded properly. This would also fit the assertion, which states that the input matrix has only one dimension.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even read the line where you initialized grey the first time.  That exact code crashes for me.  I guess there was a bug in my version of OpenCV or something was wrong with the build settings.  Thanks for checking it out for me.  I will go looking for a better/newer version