# android opencv. feature detectors . implement detect

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, feature-detection

I want to develop an android application with opencv.
I have this C++ code

```
FastFeatureDetector detector(50);
detector.detect(mGr, v);
```

this code worked correctly.

Now I want to use a different detector:

```
OrbFeatureDetector detector;
detector.detect(mGr, v);
```

But I get the following error:

```
The type 'cv::ORB' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'cv::FeatureDetector::detectImpl'
```

What is the cause?

Answer (score 0):

There is a basis class, which is [FeatureDetector](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#FeatureDetector%20:%20public%20Algorithm) (the link is to the most recent documentation).
FeatureDetector has a pure virtual method `detectImpl`. At least in your OpenCV version. All classes deriving from FeatureDetector (children classes) have to implement that method. Apparently, FastFeatureDetector implement that method, but OrbFeatureDetector not.

I see in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/genindex.html) that there are many children classes:
Apart [FastFeatureDetector](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#FastFeatureDetector%20:%20public%20FeatureDetector), also [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#DenseFeatureDetector%20:%20public%20FeatureDetector), [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#DynamicAdaptedFeatureDetector%20:%20public%20FeatureDetector), [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#FastFeatureDetector%20:%20public%20FeatureDetector), [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#MserFeatureDetector%20:%20public%20FeatureDetector), [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#PyramidAdaptedFeatureDetector%20:%20public%20FeatureDetector) and [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#StarFeatureDetector%20:%20public%20FeatureDetector).

I found also [cv::ORB](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#ORB%20:%20public%20Feature2D), but not OrbFeatureDetector. There is some "trace" [here](http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/doc/api/opencv_candidate/html/classcv_1_1OrbFeatureDetector.html) (it was "candidate" at the time), but I wonder which opencv version you are using... Have you tried to include file `orb.h`?

Anyway, I would suggest that, if you haven't, you update your opencv version to the latest one, and use `cv::ORB` like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202175/2436175

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in the [code of the feature2d module header](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp) the type OrbFeatureDetector is a synonym of the cv::ORB class:

```
typedef ORB OrbFeatureDetector;
```

Looking deeper at the implementation of the cv::ORB class I see it has no virtual methods and hence the error message you are obtaining shouldn't happen but it does if you are trying for example to declare a variable of type cv::FeatureDetector:

```
cv::FeatureDetector detector;
```

This is usually done when you want to be able to easily switch the detector implementation by setting the type of detector as that of the superclass. In this case to overcome the issue just define a pointer to cv::FeatureDetector as explained in [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840752/the-type-a-must-implement-the-inherited-pure-virtual-method-b):

```
FeatureDetector* detector;
```

Even more you can use an OpenCv's smart pointer:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector;
```